# Calling a java program from a kernel mode driver

Tags: java, kernel-mode

I have a command-line java program that I will need to call from a kernel mode driver (a MiniFilter Driver on Windows).

Is it possible ? Is there somethings I will have to take care to avoid problems ? How can I do this ?

Comment: Possibly answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/684023/3991696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java program runs in user-mode.  You can't just make a function call from kernel-mode to user-mode.  But you can communicate between the two.

Usually the user-mode program invokes the functionality of the driver by calling a user-mode IO API on a handle opened on a device object associated with the driver.  There are standard IO operations like read and write (i.e. calling Win32 APIs `ReadFile()` or `WriteFile()` in C/C++), but you can also implement your own custom/proprietary operations using `DeviceIoControl()`.  You pass an operation code and a pair of buffers: one with arguments/input to the driver, and one to receive its output.  On top of this you could build a mechanism for the user-mode program to request "calls" or messages from the driver, and the driver wouldn't complete a request until it wanted to send such a call/message.  It would pass its arguments in the *output* buffer of a pending DeviceIoControl request.  Then the program could use another DeviceIoControl() call, possibly with a different operation code, to return the results to the driver, in the *input* buffer.

You have the added burden invoking DeviceIoControl() from Java.  For that you may need to use [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) and a bit of C/C++ code in a DLL.

Beware gotchas of having a driver depend on a user-mode program.  You probably don't want to implement a blocking call in the driver that waits on the response from user-mode because the user-mode program may crash or be killed and never complete the call the driver is waiting on, and then you have a hung thread, probably in some process other than your java program's.  Even if you implement asynchronous completion of calls sent to user-mode, you probably want your calls to have a timeout mechanism, so that if the user-mode program doesn't complete the call, you can clean up any related context, such as a call identifier in a collection of pending calls.  Also look out for problems similar to those in multi-threading or multi-tasking, such as deadlock.  Also note data passed from kernel-mode to user-mode usually should be copied into the user-mode output buffer, and not contain any pointers to virtual addresses in the kernel address space or the address space of other processes.